# nuxt request error Invalid value used as weak map key

Tags: vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, http-status-code-500, nuxtjs3

[image]

I'm getting this error while trying to run : npm run dev
Although this error , the app is working fine locally , but durring production, I Got the following error

[image]

please help guys ! :)

Comment: Do not upload images of code/data/errors. Please check [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found my self writing 'dir' instead of 'div', and when I corrected it , everything worked fine :p

Comment: You should try to show what you did to fix the problem in your comment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yeah sorry I've just edited the answer ^^"

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the component you are referencing is not registered, see https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/4588 and https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/227.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem ^^' I wrote dir instead of div, that was the main problem I guess

Comment: I have that problem with components within the components/ directory, which should normally be auto imported